# Posting Div Content in Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have two php pages. In the first.php page user choose orders and a div is filling with this content, no problem. And there is a confirm button to confirm these list. When the user click this button, second.php page should be opened and the contents of the div should be displayed on that page. This is my html code for the first.php div and confirm button.

```
 <form method="post">
        <div class="col-md-5" id="orderList">
             <h3 align="centre">Order List</h3>
        </div>  
 </form>                    

 <form role="form" method="post" action="second.php">
        <div id="firstConfirmButton">
             <button type="submit" name="firstConfirmButton" id="firstConfirmButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Confirm</button>
        </div>
 </form>
```

This is the javascript code to post  the contents to second.php. First alert is working fine but second alert is not.

```
$("#firstConfirmButton").click(function() {

    var content = $('#orderList').html();
    alert(content);
        $.post("second.php", { html: content})
        .done(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        $('#confirmForm').empty().append(data);
        });
});
```

Second.php page has the confirForm div and I want to display the contents in this.

```
    <div id="confirmForm"> </div>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: The second page will have all of the posted items in the aptly named `$_POST` array.

Comment: I see array(1) { ["firstConfirmButton"]=> string(0) "" } when I tried to get data with $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is a `submit` button, so if you don't cancel the default event, the form will be submitted the regular way as well.

You need to capture the event and cancel it:

```
$("#firstConfirmButton").click(function(e) {
  var content = $('#orderList').html();

  e.preventDefault();

  // the rest of your code
```

Or in modern versions of jQuery:

```
$("#firstConfirmButton").on('click', function(e) {
  var content = $('#orderList').html();

  e.preventDefault();

  // the rest of your code
```

Comment: thnks,  I add this to my code. Now I can see the alert after .done But this time I can't open second.php?

Comment: @user3235456 You should use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`, that will give you more information. In the console you will also see error messages, for example if the path to your script is wrong. For more help, you need to specify exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: there are no errors in console,I see that when I console.log(data) in .done [Log] array(1) { (script.js, line 112)
  ["html"]=>
  string(240) "
                            <h3 align="center">Sipariş Listesi</h3>
                        <p class="items"><span>1 Adet  Tall Fat Caramel Frappuccino</span><span class="extra">Sipariş listesinden çıkarmak için tıklayın!</span></p>"
}       

<html>  
  <body>
        <div id="confirmForm"> </div>       
  </body> 
</html>

Comment: @user3235456 If you get into the `.done()` handler, your php script has executed successfully. If the result is not what you want, the problem is somewhere in your php script.

Comment: Actually I see what I want in console.log. But I need to see this in second.php. What do u think is there an error on my second.php or in first.php html part?

Comment: @user3235456 You will not *see* `second.php` when you call it using ajax. You just get the results and need to process them using javascript, for example `$('#confirmForm').html(data);` **if** you have an element with an ID of `confirmForm` in your html.

Comment: Exactly that is my problem. I get the results and in javascript  $('#confirmForm').empty().append(data); I have a div with id=confirmForm in my second.php. I need when button clicked, open second php with this content

Comment: @user3235456 Then don't use ajax but a normal form and set your value in a hidden field before you submit it. The idea of ajax is that you don't need to refresh the whole page...

Comment: How can I do that, what do u mean with a "normal form"?

Comment: I find a way and solved it with submitting form. Thanks for your warning about no need for ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You submit the form to the page **second.php** by using the **POST** method, so the data can be retrieved from the second page by using this PHP code:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

So basically, the data is stored within the `$_POST` array.

Regarding your second question. You need to avoid that you submit the default form if you first need to grab a value form a Javascript. You can do that by something like that:

```
$("#firstConfirmButton").click(function(e) {
  var data = $('#orderList').html();
  e.preventDefault();

  //...
}
```

This will avoid that your submit button submits the form without adding the desired POST data to it.

Comment: I see array(1) { ["firstConfirmButton"]=> string(0) "" } when I did this

Comment: Yes, that is the value of the `firstConfirmButton` button that you have set in the form with the attribute: `name="firstConfirmButton"`.

Comment: But I want the value of the div which id=orderList, what should I do?

Comment: Your javascript is submitting the form itself, you need to prevent the default submit. I will update my answer.

Comment: welli I did it but I can not open second.php after that update

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Please try to use FireBug to see what is happending, e.g. capture the Network Traffic or see any errors that may occur..